# Is there a way to make a private style.css file on a private github account public?

Tags: github, private

I have a private repo with a single file I want to make public (e.g. http://somedomain.com/css/style.css). Being able to do so would save me a copy/paste step.

Comment: One possible solution is to create a new public repo with the file and add it as a submodule in your original repo. It's not a perfect solution, but it would make it easier to publish the public file.

Comment: Thanks! I just found the documentation for submodules here: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules